# retrieve list element from pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming there is a `pandas.DataFrame` like:

```
pd.DataFrame([[np.nan,np.nan],[[1,2],[3,4]],[[11,22],[33,44]]],columns=['A','B'])
```

What's the easiest way to produce 2 `pandas.DataFrames` that each contains the 1st and 2nd element from every value list in the frame (nan if the position is nan).

```
pd.DataFrame([[np.nan,np.nan],[1,3],[11,33]],columns=['A','B'])
pd.DataFrame([[np.nan,np.nan],[2,4],[22,44]],columns=['A','B'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#replace NaN to [] - a bit hack
df = df.mask(df.isnull(), pd.Series([[]] * len(df.columns), index=df.columns), axis=1)
print (df)
          A         B
0        []        []
1    [1, 2]    [3, 4]
2  [11, 22]  [33, 44]

#create new df by each column, concanecate together
df3 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[col].values.tolist()) for col in df],
                axis=1, 
                keys=df.columns)
print (df3)
      A           B      
      0     1     0     1
0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
2  11.0  22.0  33.0  44.0

#select by xs
df1 = df3.xs(0, level=1, axis=1)
print (df1)
      A     B
0   NaN   NaN
1   1.0   3.0
2  11.0  33.0

df2 = df3.xs(1, level=1, axis=1)
print (df2)
      A     B
0   NaN   NaN
1   2.0   4.0
2  22.0  44.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you need with a function that return the `n'th` element of each column.

**Code:**

```
def row_element(elem_num):
    def func(row):
        ret = []
        for item in row:
            try:
                ret.append(item[elem_num])
            except:
                ret.append(item)
        return ret
    return func
```

**Test Code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[np.nan, np.nan], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[11, 22], [33, 44]]],
    columns=['A', 'B'])

print(df)
print(df.apply(row_element(0), axis=1))
print(df.apply(row_element(1), axis=1))
```

**Results:**

```
          A         B
0       NaN       NaN
1    [1, 2]    [3, 4]
2  [11, 22]  [33, 44]

      A     B
0   NaN   NaN
1   1.0   3.0
2  11.0  33.0

      A     B
0   NaN   NaN
1   2.0   4.0
2  22.0  44.0
```